# I would like to know how an out-of-sample pseudo prediction is obtained in a mixed autoregressive model

Tags: econometrics, autoregressive

I would like to know how an out-of-sample pseudo prediction is obtained in a mixed autoregressive model from a mathematical point of view. and to understand why it is not possible to make the same thing in the model in question by going out of sample.